# How to input a string containing double quotes to a matlab function through command line

Tags: matlab, command

I encounter a problem when trying to give an input string to a matlab function using the command line.

The problem is that it seems as though all double-quote characters are eaten away, and I have yet to find a functioning escape character for that.

The following is a stub of my matlab function:

```
function [value] = inputStringTest(input)

disp(input)

value = 'truc';

end
```

When calling the function in command line like so:

```
matlab -r inputStringTest('{"filename":"file.txt"}')
```

Then Matlab will open with the following content in the output window:

```
{filename:file.txt}

ans =

    'truc'
```

The double quotes are now missing from my original input, which makes it impossible to be read as a json format.

Does anybody have a solution specifically for that?

The OS is Windows Server 2016 Standard, and I am using "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" as a shell.

It would be complicated to change the actual matlab function I'm trying to call, so I have the specific constraint of being able to read the input as JSON-formatted.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: That is already really informative, thank you @CrisLuengo :)
I edited the info you asked into the post

Comment: can you use `fprintf` instead of `disp`?

Comment: Don’t know about escaping double quotes in Windows. It seems to be different for different commands. Windows is weird. Sorry, :) — but this is about properly escaping those quotes.

Comment: @ColBates-collynomial I tried fprintf and obtained the same result :/

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are probably right, but I haven't found any valid escaping method. I tried all of the following to no avail
`""    ^"   \"   ^"^"`
Thank you for your help regardless:)

Comment: You probably need to escape *inside a string*. Something like this: `matlab -r "inputStringTest('{^"filename^":^"file.txt^"}')"`

Comment: @CrisLuengo I had hopes for that idea, but weirdly enough, it produced inside matlab the following:
`{^filename:file.txt}`
So taking the first caret literally, but ignoring the following ones alongside the double-quotes

Comment: That is... very weird. Sorry I can’t be of more help. I have stayed away from Windows for 10 years now, your issue reminds me of why! :)

Comment: At this point, I would suggest that your code write a one-line M-file script that contains `inputStringTest('{"filename":"file.txt"}')`, and run that. Or do all your scripting in MATLAB. Or install Cygwin and script this is Bash. Or burn Windows and install a real OS.

Comment: The one-line M-file script seems a great idea, also, installing a real OS in my context is beyond my authority :)
Thank you @CrisLuengo for all your help